# Equity Risk Premium calculation

Tags: equities

Can someone help me understand the intuition of the following?

The formula for calculating the nominal return is:

[image]

I have the following problem for which I know the answer is A (5.4%). I was told it is because since "both equity and t-bill returns are nominal, the inflation cancels out".  How does it actually cancel out? I am just having a little trouble actually expressing that into the formulas.

```
An analyst observes the following historic geometric returns:

Equities 8.0%

Corporate Bonds 6.5%

Treasury Bills 2.5%

Inflation 2.1%

The risk premium for equities is closest to:

A) 5.4%

B) 5.5%

C) 5.6%"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be very clear about what is real and what is nominal. For example let us put a * for real rates and no * for nominal.

Let us call $r^*_f$ the *real risk free rate*. Then we have the nominal return on tbills is $r_f$ where $$(1+r_f)=(1+r^*_f)(1+\pi)$$

and the nominal return on equities is $R_n$ where
$$(1+R_n)=(1+r^*_f)(1+\pi)(1+RP)$$

You can write this in a way that shows the "inflation cancels out":
$$(1+R_n)=(1+r_f)(1+RP)$$

Applying $r_f$ = 0.025 and $R_n$ = 0.08 we get RP = 0.0536 or approximately 5.4%, without need to use the inflation rate $\pi$ = 0.021.

Comment: Thank you very much